# Postgres - Insert nearest neighbour distance into another table

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgis

So I have three tables (A, B, C). In tables A and B I have points, and I want to insert into C each row from A, and some columns from the closest point from B to each point in A, as well as the distance between them. I know that the query to get the nearest neighbour is this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (A.id5) A.state, B.way, st_distance (A.geom,B.geom) INTO C
FROM A, B   
WHERE ST_DWithin(A.geom, B.geom, 150)    
ORDER BY A.objectid, ST_Distance(A.geom,A.geom)
```

But I need to get that into a bigger INSERT query, and I tried to do it this way:

```
INSERT INTO complete(id_door, distance, id_way,Y, X, geom, check)
(SELECT A.state, (select distinct on (A.id5) ST_DISTANCE(A.geom,B.geom) from A order by A.id5, st_distance(A.geom,B.geom)), b.way, ST_Y(B.geom), ST_X(B.geom) ,B.geom, V.check
FROM A, B, C, V
WHERE
ST_INTERSECTS(A.geom, V.geom)\
AND ST_DWithin(A.geom, B.geom,150))
```

But this is not the right way, because I get the error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I cannot copy all the distances from A and B to C and then delete all but the closest because it is a huge table and I would run out of memory, so I need a way to only insert the rows with the info from the closest point from B to A.

What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance

**UPDATE:**

After some help, I have learned that I should use a Lateral in the Select query, but I'm not sure how to use it.

I need the Select to get each row in table A and find its nearest neighbour from table B, which I guess it is done using the query previously stated, and insert into table C some columns from A, some columns from its nearest neighbour (table B), and some columns from table V, which is selected by an Intersect condition. The main problem is how to organize all that into the Select so I don't get an error.

This is where I am at this point:

```
INSERT INTO C (id_door, distance, id_way,Y, X, geom, check)
(SELECT A.state, l.*, V.check
FROM A, B, C, V
lateral (select st_distance(a.geom,b.geom),  b.way, ST_Y(B.geom), ST_X(B.geom) ,B.geom
From B 
Where ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom,150))
Order by a.geom<->b.geom limit 1) l
WHERE
ST_INTERSECTS(A.geom, V.geom)
```

Comment: What is  the V table in second query?

Comment: It's just some additional info that I'm joinning to the table, but it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Ok, what do you expect as a result if your point from A intersects with many objects in V table? do you want to choose only one record from V (what conditions do you want to implement on such filter) or you want to insert all records that intersects with A?!?

Comment: V table is made of polygons that do not overlap, so each point should only overlap with one object from V. If that is not the case, I would just set an insert limit of just one of the polygons. In case the query I wrote in the update is right (is it?), I am guessing that I would have to just add another lateral right after the one for the distance with B, right? Thank you, Grzegorz

Comment: Check the latest version of the answer. I think it will be ok for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lateral join - very smart type of subquery that can reference tables outside the subquery. More about lateral you can find [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html)
-- Edited according to new information in answer --

```
Insert into C (id_door, distance, id_way,Y, X, geom, check)
select l.*
  from a,
  lateral (select a.state, st_distance(a.geom,b.geom),
                  b.way, ST_Y(B.geom), ST_X(B.geom), B.geom,
                  v.check
             from b, v
            where ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom,150)
              and st_dwithin(a.geom,v.geom,0)
              and st_intersects(a.geom,v.geom)
            order by a.geom<->b.geom, v.geom limit 1) l
```

If you want more records per each point from A then increase the limit from 1 to your desired value.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I still don't get how to include that in the INSERT query, since I also have to do a SELECT from other table which also has conditions (WHERE)

Comment: Just add another table in from clause and add where conditions simple as that

Comment: In your insert, you used a subquery in Select part (very bad practice) and have more than one record in subquery for each record from the main query. In that case, it was impossible for Postgres to insert something like that into a table. Use subquery (if you have to) in your From part and add joining conditions in where clause between your A table and records from a subquery. 
Best of all update your question and show structure of data and expected result of your select before insert will be much easier to give you a proper answer

Comment: I just updated. Hopefully you can help organizing the Select Query. Thank you very much, Grzegorz.